# Excel: Compare Contents of a Cell to a Column within an "If, Then"

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

Attempted formula:

```
=IF(S2="AK",IF(COUNTIF(AB:AB,"<>"&T2),"OTO",IF(U2 = "AK",IF(COUNTIF(AB:AB,"<>"&V2),"OTO",""))))
```

Research led me to `=COUNTIF(AB:AB,"<>"&T2)` to check the the contents of `t2` against `AB`. That part works. When I plug that into just a step further,
 `=IF(COUNTIF(AB:AB,"<>"&T2),"OTO",""))`, I lose something.

My goal in English: If the `O-State(S)` is `AK` and the `O-Zip(T)` is NOT in the list of `AK Zips(AB)`, show `"OTO"` in `H/P/O(D)`, otherwise if the `D-State(U)` is `AK` and the `D-Zip(V)` is NOT in the list of `AK Zips(AB)`, show `"OTO"` in `H/P/O(D)`, otherwise `null`.

What am I missing? (Data excerpt below)

```
D-------S--------T-------U-------V--------AB        
H/P/O   O-State O-Zip   D-State D-Zip   AK Zips  
--------    TN  37046   AK  99518   99901  
--------    AK  99613   WA  98663   99928  
--------    AZ  86004   AK  99613   99926  
--------    GA  30507   AK  99518   99835  
--------    AK  99518   NY  13676   99801
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `AND` and `OR` functions -try this version

`=IF(OR(AND(S2="AK",COUNTIF(AB:AB,T2)=0),AND(U2="AK",COUNTIF(AB:AB,V2)=0)),"OTO","")`